# How can I troubleshoot 'Connection refused' error when running Spring boot app with Eureka and Docker?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, cloud, microservices, netflix-eureka

I'm building a microservices app with spring boot the following are my config-files (serviceregistry, configserver , cloudgateway)

**cloudgateway**

```yaml
cloudgateway:
  port: 9090
spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  config:
    import: configserver:http://${CONFIG_SERVER_URL:localhost}:9296

  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id : CONSULTATION-SERVICE
          uri: lb://CONSULTATION-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/consultation/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: CONSULTATION-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/consultationServiceFallBack
            #- name: RequestRateLimiter
              #args:
                #redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
                #redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1
        - id: PATIENT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://PATIENT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/patient/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: PATIENT-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/patientServiceFallBack
            #- name: RequestRateLimiter
              #args:
                #redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
                #redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1
        - id: DOCTOR-SERVICE
          uri: lb://DOCTOR-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/doctor/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: DOCTOR-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/doctorServiceFallBack
            #- name: RequestRateLimiter
              #args:
                #redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
                #redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1
```

**configserver** defined as:

```yaml
server:
  port: 9296

spring:
  application:
    name: CONFIG-SERVER
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/cimoDevOps/ConfigServer
          clone-on-start: true


eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```

**serviceregistry**

```yaml
server:
  port: 8761


eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

The **docker commands**  which I've used to build the images and run as containers are:

```bash
docker build -t pfs2023/serviceregistry:latest .
docker build -t pfs2023/configserver:latest .
docker build -t pfs2023/cloudgateway:latest .

docker run -d -p8761:8761 --name serviceregistry  e68b3d0e99b8
docker run -d -p9296:9296 -e EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://host.docker.internal:8761/eureka --name configserver d5edc4d23bb2
docker run -d -p9090:9090 -e CONFIG_SERVER_URL=host.docker.internal -e EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://host.docker.internal:8761/eureka --name cloudgateway  5b844ba6178e
```

Here is the issue wher I've stuck **the error** ( note that serviceragistry&configserver ran with no problems )

```bash
2023-05-27 20:02:35 2023-05-27 19:02:35.266  WARN [API-GATEWAY,,] 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2023-05-27 20:02:35 2023-05-27 19:02:35.273  INFO [API-GATEWAY,,] 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/3fababcaddac:API-GATEWAY:9090 - was unable to refresh its cache! This periodic background refresh will be retried in 30 seconds. status = Cannot execute request on any known server stacktrace = com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server (give a correct solution)
```

Please suggest to fix this issue 'Connection refused'.